# No toma ni imprime la matriz declarada C

Tags: c, matrices, array

mi problema es el siguiente, no se por que no me toma la matriz como la declaro 3x3 me toma e imprime como si fuera un arreglo común, espero que me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias!

```
int main() {

    int mat [3][3];
    int i, x;

    printf("Ingresa el contenido de la matriz: \n");


    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(x=0; i<3;i++) {

            scanf("%d", &mat[i][x]);

        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(int x=0; i<3;i++) {
            printf("%d \t",mat[i][x]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: porque decis que la imprime como si fuera un arreglo comun? como esperas imprimirla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada tu error está en que en el segundo for comparas la primera variable y la incrementas, causando un compartamiento erroneo.

Cabe mencionar que en un for no puedes declarar y establecer una variable, ANSI C no lo permite, primero debes definirla e inicializarla en el for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int i,j, matriz[3][3]; // ANSI C impide declarar variables dentro de un for

    puts("Ingresa el contenido de la matriz");    

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) { // nota que se debe incrementar j y no i
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) { // lo mismo, se incrementa j y no i
            printf("%d \t",matriz[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Te faltó quitar el `int` del `for` anidado.

Comment: ya lo quite, error mío, gracias.